# Recruiter says SRE roles all filled, but they're looking for a role for me. What should I do?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search, hiring-process, recruitment

## The situation:

I was scheduled to do my phone screen on April 28th, then after rescheduling I passed my phone screen on May 5, 2019.  But my recruiter "Sarah" didn't contact me again until last Wednesday, May 22nd.  So this whole process has taken about a month so far, and I've e-mailed Sarah about the process 4 times since then.  Not sure whether this is a lot, and honestly it probably didn't have a lot of effect so maybe I just shouldn't e-mail her much?  But then again, maybe she would have replied slower if I hadn't spammed her so much?

She said [big software company] had filled all the SRE roles in that location, but that [big software company name] and [recruiter name] were looking for a place for me, since my interviewer liked my interview.

## The question:

My question is: what should I do now?  I'd been e-mailing my recruiter every 2-3 days after the first interview, trying to hear feedback, but I think I may have annoyed her a bit.  While I believe it *is* her *job* to inform me of updates in a timely manner, I also don't want to piss her off because if she's annoyed, she might tell someone who has the authority to keep me from getting the job.

## My ideas:

I could try to get another offer somewhere else just to make them move faster, give better starting salary, etc.  But I'm focusing on a Computer Science Ph.D application and would rather not throw something else into the mix

Should I keep bothering the recruiter once a week?  Apply to other jobs?  Drop off the grid til she reaches out and contacts me?  Particularly interested to hear from the recruiter perspective, if any of y'all are recruiters

Answer (score 6):

Until they make you a formal job offer then keep applying for other jobs

I personally would just assume you have not got the current job, if they decide to make an offer then the recruiter will contact you.  There is no guarantee that even if they do find another role for you that it will be one that you like.

Answer (score 4):

It is a recruiter's *job* to take emails and phone calls from their candidates. So, don't worry about annoying her, not at all. It shows her she has a live one (you).

These commercial hiring processes move slowly. Be patient. It sounds like that company was trying to fill a lot of positions. A hiring project like that is probably understaffed and hectic.

It's a **big deal** they're trying to find a place for you. They don't say that to very many candidates.

Tell the recruiter you're really excited about working for that company, and you're thrilled they are trying to find a place for you. If you have a contact at the company, tell them the same thing. Ask if there's anything more you can do to help them find that place.

If the recruiter is paid on commission, ask her if she has any other possible job openings you could interview for at that company or elsewhere. (If she's retained by the company, she probably won't help you get in to some other place.)

And, continue to live your life -- look for other jobs -- advance your studies -- whatever. If they get back to you, fine, If they dillydally for too long, you might no longer be available because you've found something else to do. Their loss.